# HTML5/Javascript multiple file upload

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, coffeescript

I'm working on a project that uses drag-drop file handling to attach files to a form.

The form is pretty simple:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="..." enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input multiple="multiple" name="files[]" type="file" />
  <div id="download-drop"></div>
</form>
```

- I can select multiple files in the FilBrowser window and they will all post to the server
- I **can't** *drag* multiple files into the dropzone - they aren't posted to the form

When I look at the server logs, I can see the files array is posted, but the files I drop onto the dropzone are not included.

Here is my javascript (actually coffeescript):

```
class Uploader
  constructor: (drop_zone, upload_button) ->
    @attachments = []

    @$upload_button = $(upload_button)
    @$upload_button.bind 'change', @manual

    @$drop_zone = $(drop_zone)
    @$drop_zone.bind 'dragenter', @noop
    @$drop_zone.bind 'dragexit', @noop
    @$drop_zone.bind 'dragover', @noop
    @$drop_zone.bind 'drop', @drop

    @render()

  # Perform a noop by preventing the default behavior and stopping
  # event propagation.
  noop: (e) ->
    e.stopPropagation()
    e.preventDefault()

  # Handler for when a file is dropped.
  drop: (e) =>
    @noop e

    for file in e.dataTransfer.files
      @attachments.push file

    @render()

  # Handle a manual file upload (using the HTML element)
  manual: (e) =>
    @noop e

    for file in e.currentTarget.files
      @attachments.push file

    @render()

  # Render helper function that redraws the HTML element
  render: =>
    @$drop_zone.html ''

    html = []
    if @attachments?.length > 0
      for attachment, i in @attachments
        html.push attachment.name

    @$drop_zone.html html.join('')

@Uploader = Uploader
```

A few things I've already looked into:

1. The class is created and both selectors are found and exist
2. `noop` works as expected
3. Scopes are all correct
4. Drop works as expected

Can someone shed light on this? I think I need to add each attachment to the files array, but I don't know how.

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Why not add some breakpoints at client side, and find out if your `drop` worked proper.

Comment: Everything works properly. There's no errors in the JS. The issue is that the files I *drop* are not added to the actual file input field

Comment: The files are added to the array and rendered on the page, but when I post the form to the server, they don't exist

Comment: How do you send the file? It seems not included.

Comment: I submit the form... I'm not sending the file with JS

Comment: Seems that's the problem. You cannot alter the `<input>`'s `files` property. You really should use XHR to send the files as you are already using HTML 5 APIs.

Comment: I can't use xhr though, it's not possible in this situation. The entire object needs to be created at once.

Comment: without XHR you can't make it work, that's it.

Comment: I think I have a solution. I can post something later. It's definitely possible, because it's working on another site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a multiple file upload status bar be implemented with simple javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675093/can-a-multiple-file-upload-status-bar-be-implemented-with-simple-javascript)

Comment: @PaulSweatte how can THIS be a duplicate of a question that is NEWER (this is 2012 versus 2013)?