# Can a multiple file upload status bar be implemented with simple javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I have a file upload on my website.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="post.php" method="POST">
<input id="uploadInput" name="uploadedfile[]" type="file" multiple>
<input type="submit" value="PREVIEW POST">
</form>
```

The code will preview this image

[image]

After a user selects the files to be uploaded it will show this image

[image]

With javascript I want a simple text to be displayed right beside it after user selection and when its uploading.

[image]

And displays upload complete when all files have been uploaded

[image]

Can the above be done with just javascript or jquery?

If yes, how?

(I just want it to be simple and just display text. I dont want a progress bar.)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer yes this can be done using JavaScript.

Longer answer, there are things to be taken care of on the bankend as well front end. Instead of doing it from scratch I would suggest you can make use of [Jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to get this done. Obviously you have not mentioned what have you tried so far. So you can look at the [wiki doc](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki) on how you can get this working.

**Update**
I did not mention this before, but you would not be able to do this without Ajax(iFrame work around/XHR file upload) and just using JavaScript.

Comment: Like the link provided by iswan. I have also already read this. The problem with the plugins available online is that they are made available as a set and they do not use the html5 code <input id="uploadInput" name="name" type="file" multiple> they usually create their own buttons in the plugins and they use ajax along with the javascript to make this work. I was hoping to find a pure javascript method of accomplishing this. And I usually like learning the things that make the internet, thats why I like working from scratch and not much of a fan of using plugins. Thank you though.

Comment: Its primarily HTML5 based and has backward compatibility. They do not create their own button if you don't want it to. Checkout [basic plugin documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin), it does not use custom CSS and you can make use of callbacks.

Comment: ill check it again. I didn't actually dive into it the first time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly simple case, but there is a bit of work involved to make this function properly cross-browser.  There are libraries out there that will take care of most of this for you.  One such library is [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com).  You can use Fine Uploader's "basic" mode which allows you to create your own UI and still get the benefit of all of the cross-browser uploading code that the library provides.

Full disclosure: I am the primary maintainer of Fine Uploader.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want upload files with ajax, Please follow this documentation. http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-ajax-file-upload/

Comment: I already read that link. But I was looking for a no ajax solution for this. Just plain javascript. Is it possible?

Comment: without ajax you can use iframe, target your form submitting to hidden iframe if it loaded you can show your message. [http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe/](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/ajax-style-file-uploading-using-hidden-iframe/) this link will help you